# REGEX - Check always start with "/"

Tags: c#, regex

In ASP.NET Validator, I want to validate a string like this - "/script/www/test/123.45" Basically, ensure that the string should always start with "/" followed by anything. 
If it does not start with "/" then its an error condition.

Comment: Maybe I'm sleepy, but I just can't find any question marks.

Answer (score 4):

```
if( !path.StartsWith("/") ) throw...
```

?

Regex seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The answers before me are great, just adding yet another extremely simple one:

```
if (path[0] == '/')
```

Using a regular expression for this would be like using power tools instead of cutlery when dining.

Comment: ) I like the rewording of the old 'sledgehammer to crack a nut' adage

Comment: If path==string.Empty then you'd need to catch an IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Yes and also if it's null (but that affects all suggested solutions and since that edge case was ignored in the rest of the answers, I ignored the other one in mine too :D). Depending on what you know about the string, they might not be needed. If it's always a valid path (due to some check earlier in the program) we can assume that it contains at least one characters (and is not null).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isValid(string sInputString)
{
  Regex rex = new Regex(@"^/");
  return rex.IsMatch(sInputString);
}
```